# Delete entity but keep one of the related one

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to delete a record of an entity but keep all the records of another entity that is related with it:

Entity record to remove is:

```
public class Ask
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

The related records that I want to keep after deleting an Ask record is of type MessageAsk :

```
public class Message
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NameFrom { get; set; }
    public string EmailFrom { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneFrom { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string MessageText { get; set; }
    public bool? Approved { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateRead { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public Member MemberFrom { get; set; }
    public Member MemberTo { get; set; }
    public MessageType MessageType { get; set; }
    public Message MessageParent { get; set; }
}

public class MessageAsk : Message
{
    public Ask Ask { get; set; }
}
```

Resuming, I want to delete an Ask and keep all related MessageAsk's.

EDIT:
I use the service Delete:

```
    private readonly IRepository<Ask> _askRepository;
    private readonly IRepository<MessageAsk> _messageAskRepository;

    public bool Delete(int askId)
    {
        try
        {
            Ask askToDelete = _askRepository.GetById(askId);

            IList<MessageAsk> relatedMessageAsks = _messageAskRepository.Query.Where(m => m.Ask.Id == askId).ToList();

            _askRepository.Delete(askToDelete);

            _askRepository.Save();

         }
        catch 
        { 
            return false; 
        }

        return true;
    }
```

And I use a repository to Delete the Entity:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected DbContext _dataContext;
    protected DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        _dataContext = context;
        _dbSet = _dataContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public T NewEntityInstance()
    {
        return _dbSet.Create();
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        if (_dataContext.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            _dbSet.Attach(entity);
        }
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

   public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        T entity = _dbSet.Find(id);

        Delete(entity);
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return _dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> Query
    {
        get
        {
            return _dbSet.AsNoTracking(); <------ SOURCE OF THE PROBLEM - I HAD TO REMOVE THE ASNOTRACKING OPTION TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM
        }
    }
```

}

Error I get now:

```
"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Messages_Asks". The conflict occurred in database "Heelp", table "dbo.Messages", column 'Ask_Id'.
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you expect that to fly in your database with -I'm assuming- all fk's in place?

Comment: Hi, sorry I did not understand your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your relationship is *optional* (that is, the foreign key from `MessageAsk` table to `Ask` table allows `NULL` values), you can do it this way:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var askToDelete = context.Asks.Single(a => a.Id == askToDeleteId);
    var relatedMessageAsks = context.MessageAsks
        .Where(m => m.Ask.Id == askToDeleteId)
        .ToList();
    // or just: context.MessageAsks.Where(m => m.Ask.Id == askToDeleteId).Load();

    context.Asks.Remove(askToDelete);
    // or DeleteObject if you use ObjectContext

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

(or `context.Messages.OfType<MessageAsk>()...` instead of `context.MessageAsks...` if you don't have a set for the derived type in your context)

You don't need to set the `MessageAsk.Ask` property to `null` explicitly here. EF will do that automatically when the `askToDelete` is removed and update the `MessageAsk` with FK = `NULL` in the database.

It does not work if the relationship is required (no `NULL`s for the FK are allowed) as you would violate a referential foreign key constraint in the database when the principal (`askToDelete`) would be deleted. In that case you need to assign the `relatedMessageAsks` to another `Ask` before you delete the `askToDelete`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have tried to use _askRepository.Delete(askId); but it raises an error saying that there is a FK in MessageAsk. You are saying to delete the Ask, but it's not what it's the ask delete supposed to do?

Comment: @Patrick: I don't understand your comment. I meant to use my code above :) I don't know what your `_askRepository.Delete(askId)` is doing exactly. Of course if it just calls Delete on the `Ask` you'll get a FK constraint exception.

Comment: I have completed the code with my repository delete operation

Comment: @Patrick: You have entity and application specific logic here. You cannot fulfill the requirement with such a simple generic repository. Somewhere (and not in a generic repo) you have to include code like the one in my answer.

Comment: I have completed the question with the code I have just tested in the Service Layer

Comment: @Patrick: Are you using the same context instance in `_messageAskRepository` and in `_askRepository`? Or do you create the context with `new` inside the repos?

Comment: I have completed the question with the constructors, I also use Autofac IoC.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25980/discussion-between-patrick-and-slauma)

Comment: Hi, any more ideias for how this is happening?

Comment: @Patrick: Did you test the foreach loop? `foreach (var item in relatedMessageAsks) item.Ask = null;`

Comment: Yes and the problem remains

Comment: @Patrick: I've just tested it and it works for me without exception. Can you show the `_askRepository.GetById` and `_messageAskRepository.Query` methods of your repository?

Comment: @Patrick: Aaaaaaahhh, there is the problem: `AsNoTracking()`!!! If you disable change tracking the whole procedure doesn't work. I suggest that you introduce two properties in your interface, like `Query` and `QueryAsNoTracking` (or a `GetQuery(bool asNoTracking)` method or similar) and then use the one that just returns `_dbSet` WITHOUT `AsNoTracking()`.

Comment: YEAH!! It's working! Thanks! So now I have to redefine in my head the way EF works! So tell me one thing, if I don't have the asNoTracking, do I still have to load all related entities of an entity to access there values? I was doing GetById for every one but now it seems that the Query without AsNoTracking brings everything with it, it's suposed to be that way? I have this in almost every action in my repository, now how do I now which one have to remain the same and which ones I change? Once again, thank you so much for your help and pacience :)

Comment: Just one last thing, why do I have to load the messages to be able to "null" then? It has to be in the context to be able to "null" them? Do I have to load all related entities to be able to "null" them? Thanks

Comment: @Patrick: The query with `AsNoTracking` does not bring everything with it. The `MessageAsks.Ask` property is only populated because the `Ask` was already in the context before, EF establishes the relationship automatically then (called "relationship fixup"). Rule of thumb is that you can use `AsNoTracking` for readonly operations (for example GET requests in a web app), but don't use it if you want to insert/change/delete (POST request in a web app). Yes, the related entities must be in the context to null them so that EF change tracking can recognize a change and write an UPDATE statement.

Comment: And to Get entities with related entities, do you recomend GET with AsNoTracking for speed and GetById to read the related entities or Get with optional IncludeProperties parameter, or GET without AsNoTracking to get all the related entities in one only operation? And the speed of this last one?

Comment: @Patrick: Depends on details. Normally GET with AsNoTracking and Include or a projection with Select if you don't need all properties.

Comment: What do you mean by projection with Select? And using Lazy Loading setting properties to virtual, is this an option in your opinion for speed and flexibility to get related entities information?

Comment: @Patrick: This comment section is a bit getting out of control and moving away from the original question :) Better ask some new questions. Regarding projection and select: google it. Regarding lazy loading: No, it's neither especially fast nor flexible.